# Add class after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div where when I click it, it adds a class of 'playing'. Then, after 10 seconds, I want to add a class of 'finished'.

I have this code, but how do I time it so after 10 seconds, it adds the class of finsihed?

```
  $('.albums img').on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('playing');
  });
```

Any help is appreciated!

---

*Thanks a ton everyone. I used this question to show ~30 students at [HackerYou](http://hackeryou.com) how to use stackoverflow to get top notch help from the community.*

Comment: Check out  .delay() function.

Comment: while you are at it @Wes - remind them to do a bit of research into their problem and ask specific questions (too broad, or not-researched questions tend to get down-voted).   Also worth noting that, when possible, posting your code to a service like JSFiddle, JSBin or similar tends to speed up the responses

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using setTimeout specifying 10 seconds delay.

```
 $('.albums img').on('click',function(){
    var $this = $(this).addClass('playing');
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $this.addClass('finsihed');
    }, 10000); //<-- Delay in milliseconds
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a ton everyone. I used this question to show ~30 students how to use stackoverflow to get top notch help from the community.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) along with [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)

```
$('.albums img').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('playing').delay(3000).queue(function () {
        $(this).addClass('finsihed')
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LewU3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function **[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)** to invoke a callback function after 10 seconds.

For example.

```
var timeout = null;

$('.albums img').on('click', function() {
    var self = this;

    $(self).addClass('playing');

    // clear previous timeout if it exists
    timeout && clearTimeout(timeout);

    // set the timeout
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $(self).addClass('finished');

    // 10 seconds
    }, 10e3);
});
```